# how to disable schema-validation with jhipster

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jhipster

I have a mysql 5.7.20 table which has a json type column, and I use this [type](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) to do mapping, and when I "./mvnw", all works.

But when I "./mvnw package -Pprod dockerfile:build", there is an exception:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [abilities] in table [ability]
```

the exception occurred after "TESTS" phase begin, according to Gaël Marziou, the test use H2 instead of mysql, and H2 does not support json type.

so how can I generate docker image in this case? disable scheme-validation for the table? or disable test on the entity Ability? how?

Please help, very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the quick and dirty solution is to use `-DskipTests`, or to disable schema validation by setting `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `none` and then exclude offending tests in the `maven-surefire-plugin` configuration.

That being said, you should definitely configure your integration tests to run against the database you will use for production, especially since your app uses vendor-specific db features (if not for development then for your CI build at a minimum).